# Modify/add/rename eloquent collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Let's say I've got eloquent collection returns from:

`$b  = Book::get();` (columns: id, book_name, pages)

`$m  = Magazine::get();` (columns, id, mag_name, type)

How do I then:

1. Combine them in the same collection.
2. Rename `->book_name/mag_name` to k
3. Add `type` and if book use 'null' as value
4. add `->hash` (str::random)

I want to keep the collection to be able to use the benifits that come with it. ie. not convert it to an array.

Laravel 7

Comment: Get result as `toArray` then `merge_array` isn't helpful??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it with collection merge method**

```
$b  = Book::get(['id','book_name as k','pages']);
$m  = Magazine::get(['id','mag_name as k','type']);

$bb = $b->map(function ($book){
    $book['type'] = null;
    $book['hash'] = Str::random();
    return $book;
});

$mm = $m->map(function ($magzine){
    $magzine['hash'] = Str::random();
    return $magzine;
});

$merged = $bb->merge($mm);

return $merged;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume we have the following collections:

```
$b  = Book::get(); //(columns: id, book_name, pages)

$m  = Magazine::get(); //(columns, id, mag_name, type)
```

Second, update the fields:

```
$books = $b->map(function ($book) => {
    return [
        'id' => $book->id,
        'k' => $book->book_name,
        'type' => null,
        'hash' => Str::random() 
    ];
});

$magazines = $b->map(function ($magazine) => {
    return [
        'id' => $magazine->id,
        'k' => $magazine->mag_name,
        'type' => $magazine->type,
        'hash' => Str::random()
    ];
});
```

Third, merge the collections:

```
$result = $books->merge(magazines);
```